# Does codes below the `setState()` get executed in React?

Tags: reactjs

React's official document says that React components will automatically start to re-render component on `setState()` calls. Does that mean any codes below the `setState()` won't get executed ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, code below `this.setState` will always be executed unless you `return this.setState` of course.

However a thing to note with calls to `this.setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous, meaning calls can and will be batched if React deems necessary.

[Complimentary JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb0z7460/)

[React#setState docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)